# help : how can i do "include(in xml)" programmatically in my app Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i have in my layout.xml this lines :

```
<include android:id="@+id/promo1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/one_promo">
</include>
<include android:id="@+id/promo2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/one_promo">
</include>
<include android:id="@+id/promo3" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/one_promo">
</include>
```

I want to do this programmatically in my Java code.

Please any help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LayoutInflater as i shown below

Define a Relative Layout in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mylayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Map it in your Java code

```
RelativeLayout mynewlayout = (RelativeLayout) findById(R.id.mylayout);
```

Use Layout Inflater

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
mynewlayout.addView(0, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_promo, this, false) );
```

Comment: thanks sankar for your reply , 
i think that i will integrate my includes in xml , but i need to change the attribute layout of each one , 
explanation : i have five includes in my layout xml,  and i want to change the layout attribute of each one programmatically , is it possible ?

Comment: @houcine: you are always welcome,try and convey me whether you reached your destination or not?

Comment: thanks sankar for your reply , i think that i will integrate my includes in xml , but i need to change the attribute layout of each one , explanation : i have five includes in my layout xml, and i want to change the layout attribute of each one programmatically , is it possible ?

Comment: @hounice: yes it is possible use LayoutInflater as i shown above, and then add  change the value of child in the first parameter of  addview method, mynewlayout.addView(0, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_promo, this, false) ); then for my second include give 1 as i shown here mynewlayout.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_promo, this, false) );

Comment: i think i dont need to add the relativeLayout in my XML code , because i already have a linearLayout on my HorizontalScrollView ,
what do u think ??

Comment: @Houcine: i gave RelativeLayout for a Example, use the Layout which is mentioned in your xml

Comment: mynewlayout.addView(0, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_promo, this, false) );

this : refer to the Activity context ? or the ViewGroup ( in ur example ,the relativeLayout) ???
because when i've tried this ,it gives me an error in this instruction 
any idea ?

Comment: @Sankar : thanks a lot my friend ,that's work great , 
but just one thing , is u need to permute arguments of method mynewLayout.addView ( View view , int index ) , :) 
many thanks my friend

Comment: @houcine: Welcome My dear friend,refer my blog for any android problem http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/