# How to update the content when button pressed in my case? (a tab-like feature)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

My **main.xml** layout simply contains **two buttons** and a **content area**, which shows below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/myBtns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:text="button one"
         />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:text="button two"
         />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
         <!--different button press will embed different content here-->

    </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to create my own **tab-like feature** that each button press will update the content(the `content_area`) below the buttons. So I have prepared two other content layout:

**content_one.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView.../>
    <Button .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

**content_two.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Gallery.../>
    <Button .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

With all my simple codes showed above, I would like to implement the feature that:

in **main.xml**:

- when `button_one` is pressed, **content_one.xml** will be embeded to the `content_area` of **main.xml**;
- when `button_two` is pressed, the `content_area` of **main.xml** will be updated to **content_two.xml**

Which means using button to create a **tab-like feature**.

My question is how to update the content_area with an external layout xml file (e.g. **content_one.xml** & **content_two.xml**) been embeded inside the `content_area` of my **main.xml** layout ?

that's:

```
button_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //What to do here?? to update the content_area in main.xml with an external xml layout
    }
});
```

**----------------UPDATE----------------------------**

I tried:

```
button_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_one, null);

            LinearLayout contentArea= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_area);
            contentArea.addView(inflatedView);
        }
    });
```

But it does not work, why?

Comment: This previous answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961522/help-how-can-i-do-includein-xml-programmatically-in-my-app-android

Comment: @ Fortega , I tried but it does not work, see my update

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LayoutInflater to create a view hierarchy from an xml file. The following code returns my xml view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_one, null);
```

The first parameter to inflate(...) is the xml file to inflate. The second parameter is an optional parent to the inflated view. In my case, I do not have one. Then you can add the view to your content area.

```
contentArea.addView(inflatedView);
```

Comment: @ spidy , I tried your method, it does not work, the external layout does not show at all

Comment: It works, the size is probably 0 if there is no content, or the view needs to be invalidated and re-drawn.

Comment: @ Spidy , I do have content.  please check my updated post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665988/why-layoutinflater-does-not-work-in-my-case