# Why LayoutInflater does not work in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

My **main.xml** layout simply contains a button and a `LinearLayout` **content_area**, which shows below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/myBtns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:text="button one"
         />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
         <!--inflate layout here-->

    </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

I have another layout (**content_one.xml**) which is going to be used to embed(inflate) to `content_area`(id value) of the **main.xml** layout:

**content_one.xml**:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView.../>
         ... 
        <Button .../>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use `LayoutInflater` to embed **content_one.xml** into `content_area` of **main.xml**:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

      private LinearLayout contentArea;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);

              contentArea= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_area);

              LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              View inflatedView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_one, null);

              contentArea.addView(inflatedView);
}
```

But it does not work, **content_one.xml** does not show in `content_area` of **main.xml** . I got the following **error message** from LogCat in eclipse

(**Please mouse right click on the following image and view image**)

[image]

why my LayoutInflater is not working? Where am I wrong?

Comment: That log is incomplete... paste the whole log (where the error occurs, of course)... and text not an image.

Comment: @ Cristian , I do not know how to copy the whole error message from eclipse LogCat console, but I upload another image which replaced the old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View` inflates correctly, but you have a `fill_parent` height on the `myBtns` layout, so the other LinearLayout is not visible. If you change it to `wrap_content` you can see the other LinearLayout.

Comment: Right!, because of that. Thank you.